# How to manipulate array values in h2?

Tags: java, arrays, h2

How can I retract and update values in an array in h2?

Since I'm trying to manage a `Set` of distinct values in an array I don't know the ordinality/position of values in the array and can
therefore only operate by value and not use the position of values in the array - if possible?

(I can live with duplicate values in the array since I load queried array values into `Set`s that will automatically filter out duplicate values.)

I can add a value with concatenation:

```sql
DROP TABLE A IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE A(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, ints INT ARRAY);
INSERT INTO A(ints) VALUES (ARRAY[1, 2]);
SELECT ints FROM A WHERE id = 1;
// [1, 2]

// Concatenate
UPDATE A SET ints = ints || 3;
SELECT ints FROM A WHERE id = 1;
// [1, 2, 3]
```

But how can I retract a specific value?

```sql
// How to retract 2?
UPDATE A SET ints = ???;
SELECT ints FROM A WHERE id = 1;
// [1, 3]

// Or, how to retract 1 and 2?
UPDATE A SET ints = ???;
SELECT ints FROM A WHERE id = 1;
// [3]
```

And how can I update one value to another?

```sql
// How to replace 1 with 10?
UPDATE A SET ints = ???;
SELECT ints FROM A WHERE id = 1;
// [10, 2, 3]

// Or, how to replace 1 with 10 and 3 with 30?
UPDATE A SET ints = ???;
SELECT ints FROM A WHERE id = 1;
// [10, 2, 30]
```

I have tried variations on unnesting the values and filter them to exclude (retract) certain values, then aggregate them back along the following (wrong) lines without success:

```sql
UPDATE A 
SET ints = ARRAY_AGG(
   (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SELECT ints FROM A) WHERE c1 != 2)
) 
WHERE id = 1;
```

UPDATE: I can get the desired filtered values:

```sql
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SELECT ints FROM A) where c1 != 2;
// C1
// 1
// 3
```

But then I can't create an array from those values (that I can set `ints` to):

```sql
VALUES ARRAY(
   SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SELECT ints FROM A) where c1 != 2
);
// C1
// [null, null]
```

Comment: It would be nice to have some of the array functions/operators from PostGreSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// How to retract 2?
UPDATE A SET ints = ARRAY(SELECT V FROM TABLE(V INT = (SELECT ints FROM A WHERE id = 1)) where V != 2);
SELECT ints FROM A WHERE id = 1;
// [1, 3]


// How to replace 1 with 10?
UPDATE A SET ints = ARRAY[1, 2, 3];
SELECT ints FROM A WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE A SET ints = ARRAY(SELECT CASEWHEN(V=1, 10, V) FROM TABLE(V INT = (SELECT ints FROM A WHERE id = 1)));
SELECT ints FROM A WHERE id = 1;
// [10, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks @mircea-sirghi. But using the function ARRAY_SLICE presumes that you know the ordinality/position of the values that you want to retract and I don't know these (same applies to TRIM_ARRAY). I want to be able to retract and replace values without having to make a query first to obtain the ordinality - if possible.

Comment: Even better, please check updated version.

Comment: Sorry, missed that I hade to click the bounty to award it to you. Done now.